# binding HTML file extension to a Jinja templates

Tags: python, pycharm, jinja2

I am using PyCharm to edit Jinja 2 templates. PyCharm seems associate this with normal HTML editor and I don't get Jinja syntax coloring. Where is the settings I can tell PyCharm to use Jinja 2 editor? Can I set this setting on per-project basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've attached a screen cap of where the setting is found:[image]

Looks like it's on a per project basis.